# First parameter optional in UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state configuration whose URL contains 2optional parameters:

```
.state("homepage", {
  url: "/:firstName/:lastName"
}
```

It will properly match `"/john/doe"` and `"/john"`, but it won't match `"//doe"`. That is, it won't match it when the first parameter is missing.

I read the [documentation on UI Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:UrlMatcher), but unfortunately I don't quite understand how to deal with this case. How could I handle it? Thank you.

Comment: is `//` valid in urls ?

Comment: wouldn't you supply a default or something? how would it know the difference between only firstname or only lastname?

Answer (score 0):

Try `url: "/{firstName:.*}/{lastName:.*}"`